# jQuery validation, how to hook error message up to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I added a jQuery validation rule, so at least one checkbox of class "require-one" has to be checked in order for the form to validate.

```
$(".require-one").rules("add", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 1,
  messages: {
    required: "Check at least one"
  }
});
```

It works great, the form does not submit and focus is set to the first checkbox.

But how do I get it to show the error message in:

```
<span id="require-one-errormessage></span>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Title says `div` but OP shows `span`.

Comment: Where is your `.validate()` method and the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default `label` element into anything by using [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement) within your `.validate()` method.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    // your other options
});
```

You could then use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to place the element within your layout.  Use a conditional to place for one type versus another.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ($(element).is(':checkbox')) {
            error.insertBefore(element); // custom
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);  // default
        }
    },
    // your other options
});
```

AFAIK, because the error element is created and toggled dynamically by the plugin, there's no way to assign an `id`, nor would there be a point.  However, you could assign a different class to all error messages, if needed, by using [the `errorClass` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorclass).